# Ajax Pagination cakePHP 3.0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, pagination

I 've a search filter in a view A, users can choose some values for the research. I want to display the results of the research, **without reloading the page**, at the bottom of the view in a table.

In a view A, I'va the search filter. In the same view, I'm doing this ajax call :

```
var tab = new Array();
    function updateResult(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'AController','action'=>'index'));?>",
                data : {dataFVariables: $("select[name='filtreVariable\\[\\]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get()},
                dataType: 'json',
                async:false,
                success: function(tab){
                    ..........
                    // Creating a table with the data in 'tab'
                    ..........
                },
                error: function (tab) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
    }
```

In the action 'index' of my controller, I retrieve a lot of data from the database. With this data, I create a table but the pagination doesn't work on this table.. 
Indeed, in my controller, I do :

```
        .............
   $this->paginate($query);

   // the data send to the ajax call
   echo json_encode($query);
```

The results are in the first page of my table but there is nothing in the others pages.

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: Check out [this](http://sandbox3.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax-examples/pagination) and the source code along with it for CakePHP 3.x for a simple solution that is fallback safe (non JS for SEO etc).

Comment: Can you please let me know that how can I get code for Ajax Pagination example in cakephp 3?

Comment: There is also a complete example and the code to it available. The linked github repo is open source.

Comment: @mark i went to link, that's very nice example for ajax pagination but i could not find code for that example. I downloaded the project form  https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-sandbox  but that is unable to run on my localhost

Answer (score 0):

First Add in your controller :

```
$condition=array();    
$this->paginate = array('conditions' => $condition, 'limit'=>'2');
$users = $this->paginate('YourModelName');
$this->set(compact('users'));
```

Then add this code in your corresponding ctp file :

```
<tr><td><?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('<< ' . __('previous', true), array(), null, array('class'=>'disabled'));?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array(   'class' => 'numbers'     ));?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next', true) . ' >>', array(), null, array('class' => 'disabled'));?></td> 
        <td colspan="4"></td></tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you add some comments ? I don't really understand because I do some 'join' in my controller so I want to paginate $query...

Comment: I believe it is not example of Ajax Pagination in cakephp 3.x ?

Comment: @DeepKakkar Yes its not for cakrphp 3.X.

Comment: If you know the cakephp3.x, then please updates the code.